# Will encodeAbi() preserve now value?

Tags: contract-development, web3js

If I have a function like the following - will the `now` value be preserved at the time encodeABI was called, or will `now` be the actual `now` time?

```
function doSomething(uint start) public {
    require(now - start < 1 day);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now will be the value of the timestamp of the current block, so the value will change with time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what do you mean by:

> ...the time encodeABI was called...

The function `encodeABI` is a **[web3 1.X.X](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-encodeabi)** while the **`now` variable refers to the timestamp of the block your transaction was included in**.

As such, the **`now` variable will remain the same across the same function call**.

Comment: Ok so it sounds like the `now` value will be the actual `now` value - not the time when the `encodeABI` function was called - since encodeABI does not send the transaction to the block chain.

Regarding your misunderstanding - I call encodeABI at a certain time then several minutes later I use the encoded abi to make a transaction. The `encodeABI` method was called before the transaction was executed (the time encodeABI was called).